# Get specifi field value from a dynamic SQL in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create and execute sql dynamically in **MYSQL**. I have a field *myColumn* and i want to show/get the value of this field. The below script will get me all data in the table,

```
SET @value:='myColumn';
SET @sql:=CONCAT("SELECT * FROM change c where c.field='",@value"'");
PREPARE dynamic_statement FROM @sql;
EXECUTE dynamic_statement;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE dynamic_statement;
```

The reason i want to do this is because I want to work on that specific field. Like execute a function on the field for e.g. repalce,substring etc etc. I know i can do any work inside `@sql` but i want to know if i can access the columns once the sql is executed.

`select @sql.myColumn` will not work. How can i achieve this?

Comment: `"SELECT "@value" FROM change c where c.field='",@value"'"` should be work as `@sql`

Comment: Hi @RyffLe Did you see my edit on the question ?

Comment: 'if i can access the columns once the sql is executed' - No you can't

Comment: @P.Salmon No way of getting the results in a variable and access them after as well I presume.

Comment: No there isn't. SQL destroys after every statement the Variable (Garbage collector) The Only way I think to solve this is to create a view after every execution. But this isn't dynamic anymore.

Comment: MYSQL does not have table variables , you could push 1 value into a user defined variable but that doesn't seem useful and pushing all results into a table does not seem useful either since then you would processing 2 tables instead of one.

Comment: I think you should provide sample data and desired results.  You have gone down the wrong path in working with your data.  And your data model is not clear -- nor what you want to accomplish.